# DataTables "nCell is undefined" error with valid XHTML

Tags: jquery, xhtml, datatables

DataTables 1.9.3 with jQuery 1.8.1 dies on a **validated** (XHTML 1.0 Transitional, ISO-8859-1 encoded) page where I'm trying to use it, with the following message at page ready:

> TypeError: nCell is undefined

<strike>Is there perhaps a size limit to the tables DataTables can handle? It's the biggest page I've tried yet, almost 700KB (mainly because of embedded styles), with one table of >520 lines and one with >160 lines.</strike> It also fails on a smaller version of the same table. Both tables have the *`sortable` class*, one contains *checkboxes* and the other contains *radio buttons*, and both have a single *`<thead>` and `<tbody>`* section. Unfortunately I can't post the full page since the data is company internal, but I'll try to create a minimal sample.

DataTables initialization code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sortable').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out DataTables doesn't know what to do with a **`@colspan`** in the last line of the table - I had to move the contents of it outside the table, and remove the row, then it worked.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a `tfoot`?

Answer (score 5):

was having same issue, as here, just in my case, columns count was lower than, sorting setting of datatables.
    `"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 11 ] }]`

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me the exact error when the amount of columns were not a Matrix N * M .... That is, I exported an Excel spreadsheet as a webpage just to test the functionality with a fixed content for a report at work, and after cleaning up with find and replace, didn't realize that there was a conditional comment for unsupported uneven columns. Thought it was a class, and trying it now after adding "" instead of colspan, so I believe the error itself is trying to say that the jQuery plugin can't find the element to assign a class odd or even while going through the structure.. My 2 cents worth fwiw. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when the no of columns specified were not equal to the actual columns in the files.

Try changing the aoColumns option

```
('#chart table).datatable({
    "aoColumns": [
                        null, null // as many columns you have
 ] 

});
```